# Failed recovery mode in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, recovery-mode

I ran out of free space in my ubuntu, I could not load ubuntu normally as before, so I was working through recovery mode but I did not understand what happened that recovery mode also failed so when I click on advanced options for Ubuntu, and then choose recovery mode, It just gives me the error message of failed recovery mode. How can I repair this issue?

Comment: You could try booting with a  Live-USB, mounting the partition that is full, copying off pictures and videos and deleting them. Then hopefully you can boot normally without recovery mode.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that does not help since I do not have any extra pics and videos on my ubuntu to delete and I need to go into recovery mode

Comment: You "repair" the issue exactly the way @WinEunuuchs2Unix wrote: You boot from a LiveUSB and then delete *something* that was filling your space. If you still want those files, copy them to another media instead of deleting.